# Do I need a one-to-many relation, assuming the parent table will consist of a single row forever?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a simple portfolio page with an Admin Panel to fill some of the pages with content - photos and text.

There's the About page. The page has text content and contact details. It also can have photos. I structured the tables like this:

**about**

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| id |        email        |    phone    |             description             |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | example@example.com | 123 456 789 | We are company X and we're awesome. |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
```

**about_photos**

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | deleted |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | 1.jpg |       0 |
|  2 | 2.jpg |       0 |
|  3 | 3.jpg |       1 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

**The question is:** Do I need to relate the `about_photos` to the only record in the `about` table with a foreign key?

On one hand, it doesn't hurt me and gives me the possibility to define the table with a `ON DELETE [...]`.

On the other hand, there is (and will be) only one About page and it's not like someone will go and delete the About page record by hand.

On the third hand (I know), not including the foreign key "feels" weird, even though I see no real-life value in including it.

Comment: Why would a single page have its own table?

Comment: Well, it's a standalone entity, with its own specific content and possible relations. What would you suggest? I'm open to ideas.

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` implies that you're going to potentially delete the row in `about` at some point?  Which implies that you're going to insert new rows?  So, this feels like you're going to have multiple pages represented in this structure?  In which case, implementing a relationship between these tables makes sense.  *(Unless you mean `site` instead of `page`?)*  If you're really only ever going to have one row in the `about` table, then you may be better served with a single table for all of the static properties *(one row for email, one row for phone, one row for photo url...)*.

Comment: @MatBailie My bad, the `ON DELETE CASCADE` was merely meant to be an example of what I could possibly use the foreign key for if I really needed to. And yes, there will always be a single About entry. It's a small, single-site project with pages like Home, About, Gallery, etc. All good points, though, thanks. It sounds like one table for one page is a bad idea, based on your comments here.I will rethink the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create the foreign key

> it's not like someone will go and delete the About page record by hand.

Your aren't always be there to watch the db so you build it with all the restriction so the next guy doesn't have the chance to mess up.

Comment: True. Honestly, I didn't believe my own words fully when I was writing this ;)